# Snap.svg and dynamic text

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to place text dynamically into an svg created by Snap, this is what I tried:

```
this.setContent(
  `<svg id="${this.svgId}"></svg>`
);

var snap = Snap($(`#${this.svgId}`)[0]);
text = "asdfsdfsdsfd";

var rect = snap.paper.rect(0, 0, 50, text.length*3 + 4, 10);
snap.text(1.5,10, text);

console.log("rect", rect);
console.log("snap", snap);

rect.attr({
  fill: "#FFFFFF",
  fillOpacity: 0.6,
});
```

I get this: [image]

I want the rectangle to be just a little bigger than the text, but there must be a better way to do it than to calculate the length and height of the text, and that's assuming the font size won't change.

This is the only result I found regarding text in the snap docs: http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Paper.text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using getBBox() on the text element, and use that to figure the size of the rect. getBBox() wll give you the x,y,width,height,x2,y2 figures to help.

```
var text = s.text(0,0,'blah blah')
var bb = text.getBBox();
var rect = s.rect(bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height )
```

Adjusting with offsets for whatever padding etc that you want. You may also need to allow for stroke widths, as I don't think that's included.

Comment: What is `s`? the snap object?

Comment: It's your paper or svg, typically from s=Snap('#mysvgcontainer') or s=Snap(800,800) or whatever to set it up. In your example, I'm not quite sure if its snap or snap.paper as you've used both.

Comment: Yeah the docs were confusing, how can I place that rectangle in `var snap = Snap($(`#${this.svgId}`)[0]);`?

Comment: snap.rect(bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height ) I would assume (if snap is your Snap paper/svg object).

Comment: By doing this http://i.imgur.com/rcV9HoQ.png I don't see the rectangle, just the text... http://imgur.com/SczBcYO

Comment: Could it be that something there is asynchronous? If I do `text.getBBox()` afterwards from the console I get non zero values.

Comment: It shouldn't be, can you show a basic jsfiddle highlighting the problem ?

Comment: You needed to use 'snap' rather than 's' http://jsfiddle.net/aw8zvsbn/80/

Comment: Oh I did that in my original code, well I don't know why it doesn't work, nvm, thanks for the help.